# Java library method or algorithm to estimate aggregate string similarity?

Tags: java, database, algorithm, cluster-analysis, hash

I have responses from users to multiple choice questions, e.g. (roughly):

```
Married/Single
Male/Female
American/Latin American/European/Asian/African
```

**What I want is to estimate similarity by aggregating all responses into a single field which can be compared across users in the database - rather than running queries against each column.**

So, for example, some responses might look like:

```
Married-Female-American
Single-Female-European
```

But I don't want to store a massive text object to represent all of the possible concatenated responses since there are maybe 50 of them.

So, is there some way to represent a set of responses more concisely using a Java library method of some kind.

In other words, **this method would take `Married-Female-American` and generate a code, say of `abc` while `Single-Female-European` would generate a code of, say, `def`**?

This way if I want to find out if two users are `Married-Female-Americans` I can simply query a single column for the code `abc`.

Comment: What is the method by which `Married-Female-American` becomes `abc` but by which `Single-Female-European` becomes `def`?  I would have assumed you'd want `dbf`...

Comment: Also, your question title asks for an algorithm to calculate similarity, but your question body asks for an algorithm merely to perform string conversions...

Comment: Currently, are you storing all answers in one column in your database?

Comment: The obvious (?) solution is to represent the first choice as one bit, the second as  one bit, the third as three bits, and pack them all into an integer.  Is there some reason that doesn't work?  That is, do you need to compare for similarity, or compare a semi-freeform field?  Your question implies you want similarity -- how do you want to measure the similarity?

Comment: @Dave No, I'm currently storing all answers in separate columns but I want to create a new single column with an aggregate code for comparisons.

Comment: Normally you would use enums in columns. Any reason why you don't want to use multiple columns? That sounds like a really weird requirement. Database restriction?

Comment: @mquander You're on the right track. I can't know all of the possible responses. `Semi-freeform` is a good way of putting it.

Comment: What does "semi-freeform" mean?  Either it's strictly multiple-choice, or it's completely "freeform".  I can't see anything in-between...

Comment: @Milkmate if you don't have all the choices beforehand, consider [clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) the data before processing.

Comment: @alf: Good tip. Looking at that now. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if it was a multiple choice question, you have choices enumerated. That is, numbered. Why not use `1-1-2` and `23-1-75` then? Even if you have 50 answers, it's still manageable.

Now if you happen to need the *similarity,* aggregating is the last thing you want. What you want is a simple array of ids of the answers given and a function defining a *distance* between two answer arrays. Do not use Strings, do not aggregate. Leave clean nice vectors, and all the ML libraries will be at your service.

To quote a Java ML library, try http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/

**Update:** One more thing you may want to try is [locality sensitive hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_sensitive_hashing). I don't think it's a good idea in your case, but your question looks like a request for it. Give it a try.

Comment: +1: Cramming a whole bunch of fields into one is likely to make operations far harder (not just the similarity matching, but also standard indexing/lookup operations), as well as reducing maintainability.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth my point exactly. The tools are perfectly sharpened for a multiple-feature data. Making one feature out of 50 is akin to getting into a kung fu fight in restrains: nice challenge, perhaps, but very likely to be painful.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a finite number of options (multiple-choice seems to imply this)?

It is a common technique for performance to go from strings to a numerical data set, by essentially indexing the available strings. As long as you only need identity, this is perfect. Comparing an integer is much faster than comparing a string, and they usually take less memory, too.

A character is essentially an integer in `0-255`, so you can of course use this.

So just define an alphabet:

```
a Married
b Single
c Male
d Female
e American
f Latin American
g European
h Asian
i African
```

You can in fact use this even when you have more than 256 words, if they are positional (and no single question has more than 256 choices). You would then use

```
a Q1: Married
b Q1: Single
a Q2: Male
b Q2: Female
a Q3: American
b Q3: Latin American
c Q3: European
d Q3: Asian
e Q3: African
```

Your examples would then be encoded as either (variant 1) `ade` and `bdg` or (variant 2) `aba` and `bbc`. The string should then have a fixed length of 50 (if you have 50 questions) and can be stored very effectively.

For comparing answers, just access the `n`th character of the string. Maybe your database allows for indexed substring queries, too. As you can see in above example, both strings agree only on the second character, just like the answers agreed.